# jQuery and 'this' issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to achieve an effect on the hr element.  When the user hovers over the logo I want the width of the hr element below to change to 100% and also add some opacity.

Currently all the hr elements change at the same time. How can I make it so only the image hovered on changes?

This is my code currently

```
$('.img-fluid').hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        opacity:0.5
        },200);
    $('.logo').animate({
        width:'100%'
    },200);

},
 function(){
    $(this).animate({
        opacity:1
        },200);
    $('.logo').animate({
        width:'50%' 
    },200);
});

$('.img-fluid').hover(function(){
    $('.logo',this).animate({
        width:'100%'
    },200);
}, function(){
    $('.logo',this).animate({
        width:'50%' 
    },200);

});
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="row col-md-11 mx-auto">
    <div class="col-md-2 mx-auto">
      <img src="images/logos/lyle_scott.png" class="img-fluid">
      <hr class="logo"> </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 mx-auto">
      <img src="images/logos/makser.jpg" class="img-fluid">
      <hr class="logo"> </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 mx-auto">
      <img src="images/logos/maxfli.jpg" class="img-fluid">
      <hr class="logo"> </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 mx-auto">
      <img src="images/logos/mizuno.png" class="img-fluid">
      <hr class="logo"> </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 mx-auto">
      <img src="images/logos/odyssey.jpg" class="img-fluid">
      <hr class="logo"> </div>
  </div>
```

Also I would like to be able to shorten this code down and perform it all in the one function. Currently each effect is handled separately.

See this image for a better idea: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSIdj.png

Comment: Is `logo` the CSS class you have given to the `hr` elements? Please provide the HTML code. We cannot guess it from the image.

Comment: can you add html code, so we can know the elements and their classes

Comment: Hi, added it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply use the class in the selector, you will select all elements with the same class. You will need the jQuery `.siblings()` method in this case to get the right `hr` element, as the `hr` is located at the same level/in the same parent element as your image.

```
$(".img-fluid").on("mouseenter", function () {
    $(this).animate({
        opacity:1
    },200);
    $(this).siblings('.logo').animate({
        width:'100%'
    },200);
});
$(".img-fluid").on("mouseleave", function () {
    $(this).animate({
        opacity:0.5
    },200);
    $(this).siblings('.logo').animate({
        width:'50%'
    },200);
});
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks. Also its nice the way you set the opacity lower and then higher or 'brighter' on hover. Didn't think of that at all :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the structure of your `HTML` but I assume that you hover on an `img-fuild` class then you have the logo element inside of it.

```
 $(".img-fluid").on("mouseover", function () {
         $(this).animate({
            opacity:0.5
            },200);
        $(this).find('.logo').animate({
            width:'100%'
        },200);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can, I might use css rather than jQuery for something like this using animations or transitions. Using :hover, you won't have to worry about trying to only effect a single element since that's already how it works.

Comment: Yeah I knew I could achieve this using CSS but i'm just starting to learn jQuery so I figured it would somewhat more beneficial to do it this way.